# From Jenkins, I am trying to run a python script that executes a make -f command after setting some environment variables.

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins

From Jenkins I need to run a Python script that:

-Gets some version
-sets some variables (i.e. @set TOOL_ROOT=C:/gccnew/powerpc-ibm-eabi
                           @set path=%TOOL_ROOT%/bin;%path%)
-run make -f makeFile clean all .....

I need to know if it fails and let Jenkins know about it.

I've been looking at Popen, and subprocess.check_output but they don't seem to work:

```
cmd = """
@echo off &
@set TOOL_ROOT=C:/tool &
@set path=%TOOL_ROOT%/bin;%path% &
"""

#print cmd
makeCommand = cmd + "make -f makefile clean all strip"

# Run make file
makeResult = subprocess.check_output( makeCommand, shell=True)
```

*How can I set the variables, run it, and get a sensible output that lets me know if it has failed or not?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins build steps expects a success as a **zero** value returned from the process and failure as a **non zero** value.
As long as you exit the batch file with 0 for success and 1 for error, Jenkins will know how to end.

In batch files, the result of a call to a process is in the **%ERRORLEVEL%** variable.
You can simple add a **exit %ERRORLEVEL%** after the last command in the file.

Note that this will return the result of the last command only. You should put some logic in checking all processes that you run.

I hope this helps.